# Can't align element. What's the way to fix this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

I'm trying to make the icon for hamburger menu and align it with flexbox. But I can't. My icon is going to the left (beyond the menu and the browser screen), weird top indent appears.

There's my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;
}

label {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="click">
  <label for="click">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And also I wondered why label doesn't see its child elements. I mean the parent with `position: relative/fixed/absolute` have to see its child with `position: absolute`.

What am I missing?

Comment: right:0 to span elements?

Comment: @Temani Afif it worked, but there's still top indent. Do you know what caused that strange location of label on the page? I can't find any information about this behaviour

Comment: your label has 0 width/height and is placed at the at the end of wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the button for the hamburger menu can be made in different ways.

Check out my example. Now your tag `<label>` has a **height** and **width**, and this means that you can now adjust the height of the lines - `<span>`.

And now, you can see the background color - `background: red`.

Also, I added a rule `right: 50px` for `label`. Now you can adjust the padding.

I marked all the edits in css.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

span {
  /*position: absolute;*/ /*remove*/
  z-index: 1;
  /*width: 70px;*/ /*remove*/
  width: 100%; /*add*/
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;
}

label {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/ /*remove*/
  
  display: flex; /*add*/
  flex-direction: column; /*add*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*add*/
  width: 70px; /*add*/
  height: 50px; /*add*/
  right: 50px; /*add*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="click">
  <label for="click">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will more easy if you set your hamburger menu position to relative, and then give each of them margin

from this,

```
  span {
  /*position: absolute;*/ /*remove*/
  z-index: 1;
  /*width: 70px;*/ /*remove*/
  width: 100%; /*add*/
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;
}
```

to this

```
span {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 70px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
  }
```

you see no need to edit each of humberger lines